# How can I invalidate access token from Linkedin to sign out ?

Tags: java, rest, linkedin-api, access-token

My application sign in to LinkedIn successfully using OAuth 2.0. However, I cannot find a way to sign out. I have searched on the web I need to delete access token from my application. My application uses scribejava library.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12495942/3585278

Comment: What have you already tried? Post some code

Comment: @Danieboy it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can mark the questions as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer, it should solve your issues:

[Unable to logout from linkedin using javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489017/unable-to-logout-from-linkedin-using-javascript-api/12495942#12495942)

Code sample from answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: mykey
  authorize: true
  onLoad: onLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad() {
  try {
    IN.User.logout();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  setTimeout("goToHome()", 10000);
}

function goToHome() {
  location.href="index.php";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't copy-paste answers. You should flag as duplicate instead. There is no need to duplicate content.

Comment: @Tunaki What if the question isn't a duplicate...but it has an answer that's been posted before to a different question?